# Get last used path from explorer in powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-file-explorer

Is it possible to get the path of the folder that was used by the user in the file explorer last in powershell?

For example, if you have the folders "Programming/Projects" on your desktop and you go to this folder through the file explorer. Then I want to execute something in powershell by pressing a button which gets this path and opens VS Code in this path (in this case "code C:\Users\user\Desktop\Programming\Projects". But I don't know how I can get this path. I don't want to get it through a dialog.

Comment: You can add a context menu to the right click like it is done [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/165268/how-to-add-open-powershell-here-to-the-context-menu-in-windows/)

Comment: The point is my notebook has a stream deck and I want to use these buttons somehow. But thanks anyway, I will consider this solution